# Creating a row vector from slice of matrix

Tags: vector, julia, slice

I was wondering if anyone has a clear way to return a row vector from a slice of a matrix?

```
matrix[k,:]
```

actually returns a vector of size `(n,)`, so it's automatically treated by Julia as a *column* vector, not a row vector. So far, I've been using the syntax

```
matrix[k,:]'
```

to represent the row vector of size `(1,n)`, but somehow this seems clunky and not at all intuitive that this is a row vector and not a column vector. Most mathematicians I've talked to assume incorrectly that this isn't a row vector.

Is there a more Julianic way to get a row vector slice, that is more clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
julia> m=rand(1:10,3,4)
3×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  5  3  9
 6  8  1  5
 4  5  3  4

julia> m[[1],:]
1×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  5  3  9
```

Note that it is almost always better to use `view`s to avoid data copying:

```
julia> @view m[[1],:]
1×4 view(::Array{Int64,2}, [1], :) with eltype Int64:
 4  5  3  9
```

#### Explanation:

Selection of `Array` elements can be done either by using scalars or by using iterables. Using a scalar causes the given dimension to be dropped. On the other hand using a collection does not drop the dimension. For better explanation consider yet another example:

```
julia> m[1:1,1:1]
1×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 4
```

You can see that only one element has been selected but the dimensions have not been dropped. Hence you end-up having a `Matrix` (that is 2-dimensional `Array`) having only one row and one column.

#### EDIT (comment by  Colin T Bowers - thank you!)

Deciding whether or not to use views is not trivia - mostly this is whether your code benefits from buffering. However, surprisingly often `view`s are better.

```
julia> const vals = rand(200,200);

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime sum(view(vals,1,:))
  169.392 ns (1 allocation: 48 bytes)
95.08924081258299

julia> @btime sum(vals[1,:])
  184.384 ns (1 allocation: 1.77 KiB)
95.08924081258299
```

Let us define our own summing function.

```
julia> function mysum(a::AbstractVector{A}) where A <: Number
    v = zero(A)
    @inbounds @simd for i in 1:length(a)
        v += a[i]
    end
    v
end;

julia> @btime mysum(view(vals,1,:))
  141.931 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
95.08924081258299

julia> @btime mysum(vals[1,:])
  174.934 ns (1 allocation: 1.77 KiB)
95.08924081258297
```

It can be clearly seen that when you are summing row once `view`s are still better. 
Last but not least summing by columns is of course several time faster and copying the data is expensive as hell:

```
julia> @btime sum(view(vals,:,1))
  25.828 ns (1 allocation: 48 bytes)
96.04440265541243

julia> @btime mysum(view(vals,:,1))
  13.927 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
96.04440265541243

julia> @btime sum(vals[:,1])
  167.745 ns (1 allocation: 1.77 KiB)
96.04440265541243
```

Comment: Fantastic! Just what I was looking for. If you could just add why `m[[1],:]` is different than `m[1,:]` to your answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Surprisingly, for row vectors, it is sometimes much better to *not* use `view`. This is because matrices in Julia are stored in column-major order, and so a row slice from a matrix is not contiguous in memory. Many common BLAS operations, like summing a vector, have fantastic optimizations when the input is contiguous in memory, so in many cases the time wasted by making a new copy of a row slice is more than offset by the fact that the new copy is contiguous in memory and can take advantage of BLAS optimizations.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll I added explanation per your request.

Comment: @ColinTBowers surprisingly view or not view decision is not always so obvious. My experience is that you need to benchmark every time - see my extended edit.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Wow, I wasn't actually requesting you add an explanation, but you've done a great job of it. Totally agree that if your routine is performance critical then the best bet is to benchmark since it isn't always clear which approach will dominate. Having said that, the `sum` on `view` performance is impressive, as well as your optimized routine. I have a vague memory of doing this test back on v0.3, and making a new copy was the clear winner back in those days. The language has come a long way!

Answer (score 0):

To create a vector from a matrix row, you can simply use:

```
Vector(m[i, :])
```